# Use pandas style for table outputs with custom min/max highlighting

Tags: pandas, latex, styles

I am using Pandas for basic evaluations and use it to output Latex tables.
I am outputting various error metrics for most metrics and the results are fine (the smallest error is shown in green).

```
style = df.style.highlight_min(color='darkgreen', axis=0).highlight_max(color='darkred', axis=0)
latex_table = style.to_latex(multicol_align="c", siunitx=True, hrules=True, [..])
```

Now I also output the so-called Q-Error (basically `max(prediction/actual, actual/prediction)`). This error is ideally 1.0 when completely accurate. With the standard Pandas styling, I cannot mark the best error of 1.05 over smaller numbers like 0.6 (which are larger error values).

Is there a way to customize highlights?

Comment: `Styler.apply` and `Styler.applymap` allow you to add completely customisable highlighting functions. `highlight_min` is just included for simplicity since it's a common operation but the scope is limited to your imagination and ability to code python.